# CSS - Bootstrap 3 - media queries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

i need help in my **CSS** code, am used **bootstrap 3** my problem is when i try to use media queries not working

> juste my code css but other code bootstrap working

on my device **Huawei p8 lite** so please i need a **solution for all device**

Comment: You didn't post any code. You don't have to make css media queries because it's already in the Boostrap css

Comment: Use grid specific class like `col-md-12` `col-sm-12` `col-xs-12`........

Comment: Anyone ever seen media queries for Huawei? I cant get find them anywhere?